# Cannot create a window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to create a simple window but it does not work for some reason. I have actually tried this for the past few months. Even used some old code and it does not run at all for whatever reason.

Actually, the registerclass function does not return anything ever but this happened in the past too but I was still able to create a window. Nothing works this time

I tried:

- Providing a valid value for all of the members of WNDCLASS
- Running Debug/Release
- Running as administrator
- Using GetLastError (always returns 0)
- Providing different class names, because I know some don't work for some reason, and also window names

This is my code:

```
WNDCLASSEXW lpClass = WNDCLASSEXW{ 0x00 };
lpClass.cbSize = sizeof(decltype(lpClass));
lpClass.style = (CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW);
lpClass.lpfnWndProc = ScreenProcess;
lpClass.hInstance = GetModuleHandleW(nullptr);
lpClass.lpszClassName = L"__TEST__";
lpClass.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));

RegisterClassExW(&lpClass);

if (HWND hwnd = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_APPWINDOW, lpClass.lpszClassName, L"abc", WS_POPUP,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 500, 500, nullptr, nullptr, lpClass.hInstance, nullptr))
{
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
}

printf("%d", GetLastError());

for (;;) {};
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/learnwin32/window-messages

Comment: Why would adding that help at all? It's not even creating the window? I was going to add it anyway but I can't even create the window

Comment: Creating a window requires processing events.  Your infinite loop is not doing anything except heating the CPU.

Comment: my infinite loop is there to keep the console open in case the window just took a bit to show up. Could have went for a getchar or something though. Does not help me with my initial problem at all though

Comment: @stark any insight in what could be wrong? it seems like nobody else has anything to say and it'll suck for this seemingly easy problem to go unsolved

Comment: "*the registerclass function does not return anything ever*" - yes, it does. It returns 0 on failure, and non-zero on success. But you are not checking that. And `GetLastError()` returns a valid error code if either `RegisterClass()` or `CreateWindowEx()` fails, but you are not calling it at all. Despite your claims, these functions DO work when used properly, and DO fail when used incorrectly. Also, you did not show what your `ScreenProcess()` is actually doing. For all we know, it is not processing messages correctly, even the messages sent to the window before `CreateWindowEx()` exits.

Comment: I removed the check for registerclass because it was never passing it and I figured maybe it was returning 0 but actually working. And what do you mean im not checking the return value of createwindow, im passing it to hwnd and then using a printf to check it. and getlasterror returns 0 every time. did you try running my code to see if it works? I tried using the standard win32 project with windows and that does not work either. what could be wrong with my pc?

Comment: "*I removed the check for registerclass*" - don't do that. "*it was never passing it*" - and that should tell you something, like maybe you are passing bad data to it. Use `GetLastError()` to verify. "*I figured maybe it was returning 0 but actually working*" - nope, it doesn't work that way. "*what could be wrong with my pc?*" - nothing you PC does can affect this code. You simply need to make sure you are using the API correctly to begin with.

Comment: The window for sure has been created but immediately quits. You should block on `while` loop to get the messages: `while(GetMessage(&msg, 0,0,0)){ DispatchMessage(&msg}; //...`

Comment: I changed WS_POPUP to WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE in the createwindow call and now it actually works, it gives a value to the hwnd. why is that?

Comment: @AAAbbbCCCddd: `HWND` can have the value `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` which is `-1` on failure or any other values on success.

Comment: @Raindrop7 `CreateWindowExW` won't return `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` if it fails. It'll return `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

Did you define your window procedure as something like this?

```
LRESULT CALLBACK ScreenProcess(
    HWND hWnd,
    UINT msg,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam
)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And instead of the infinite loop, place this:

```
MSG msg{0};

while(GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)){
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

Also, the `cbSize` of the `WNDCLASSEXW` should be `sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW)`. Also change the `CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));` to `GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);`

Hope this helps!

Comment: yep the procedure is exactly like that. I did pass it as an argument to the WND class after all. If it was wrong, it wouldve told me. And sizeof(decltype(lpClass)) is the same as what you gave me, decltype returns the type of the variable you give it. And I also tried with no coloring at all and with what you gave me but it also does not work sadly. Did my code work on your machine?

Comment: Don't forget the `WS_VISIBLE` flag. He can use that in place of ShowWindow/UpdateWindow.

Comment: Well I could but it wouldn't fix my problem

Comment: Shouldn't you `return TRUE;` after `PostQuitMessage(0);`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo isnt that supposed to be called to send a wm_quit message to the window to close it? why return?

Comment: `PostQuitMessage(0);` _will_ return - but I mixed up the return values one should use.. Returning `0`  means that the `WM_DESTROY` message was dealt with by the app, not the other way around as I thought it was.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version of your code that's working in VS2017 (using C++17). I've added debug prints so that you can see `ScreenProcess()` receiving mouse movements etc. I've also added a class (`WindowsClassRegistrator`) for handling one of the resources you allocate to show how you can extend the existing C structs to handle releasing of resources automatically.

I added a mapping between common Windows messages and their macro names to make it easier to follow what you actually get into your `WndProc`. Unknown Windows messages are collected and displayed when you click close on the app (on the task bar) so you can extend the messages you'd like to handle/display as you go.

I also added assertion function templates for throwing exceptions with proper errors messages that you can use around all WinAPI functions that have an easy way of checking if they've succeeded or not.

```
#include "pch.h" // if you use precompiled headers
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Windowsx.h> // GET_X_LPARAM, GET_Y_LPARAM
#include <Olectl.h> // OCM_BASE
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_set>

// --- bug hunting support functions start ---
std::string GetLastErrorString() {
    DWORD le = GetLastError();
    LPSTR  lpBuffer = nullptr;

    if (FormatMessageA(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        0, le, 0,
        reinterpret_cast<LPSTR>(&lpBuffer),
        0, NULL
    ))
    {
        std::string rv(lpBuffer);
        LocalFree(lpBuffer);
        return rv;
    }
    else return std::to_string(le);
}

struct win_error : public std::runtime_error {
    win_error(const std::string& prefix) :
        std::runtime_error(prefix + ": " + GetLastErrorString())
    {}
};

// assert that a function does NOT return a specific value
template<typename T>
inline T AssertNEQ(T value, const char* funcname, T got_value) {
    if (value == got_value) throw win_error(funcname);
    return got_value;
}

// assert that a function DOES return a specific value
template<typename T>
inline T AssertEQ(T value, const char* funcname, T got_value) {
    if (value != got_value) throw win_error(funcname);
    return got_value;
}
// --- bug hunting support functions end ---

class WindowsClassRegistrator : public WNDCLASSEXW {
    ATOM wca;

public:
    WindowsClassRegistrator(WNDPROC lpfnWndProc) :
        WNDCLASSEXW{ 0 }, wca{}
    {
        this->cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW);
        this->style = CS_SAVEBITS | CS_DBLCLKS | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        this->lpfnWndProc = lpfnWndProc;
        this->hInstance =
            AssertNEQ<HMODULE>(NULL, "GetModuleHandleW", GetModuleHandleW(nullptr));
        this->lpszClassName = L"__TEST__";
        this->hbrBackground = static_cast<HBRUSH>(GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH));
        this->wca = 
            AssertNEQ<ATOM>(NULL, "RegisterClassExW", RegisterClassExW(this));
    }
    WindowsClassRegistrator(const WindowsClassRegistrator&) = delete;
    WindowsClassRegistrator(WindowsClassRegistrator&&) = delete;
    WindowsClassRegistrator& operator=(const WindowsClassRegistrator&) = delete;
    WindowsClassRegistrator& operator=(WindowsClassRegistrator&&) = delete;
    ~WindowsClassRegistrator() {
        AssertNEQ<BOOL>(FALSE,
            "UnregisterClassW", UnregisterClassW(GetAtomAsStr(), this->hInstance));
    }

    inline LPCWSTR GetAtomAsStr() const noexcept {
        return reinterpret_cast<LPCWSTR>(this->wca);
    }
    inline HINSTANCE GetInstance() const noexcept {
        return this->hInstance;
    }
    inline LPCWSTR GetClassName() const noexcept {
        return this->lpszClassName;
    }
};

std::multimap<UINT, std::string> messages = {
    {WM_NULL, "WM_NULL"},
    {WM_CREATE, "WM_CREATE"},
    {WM_DESTROY, "WM_DESTROY"},
    {WM_MOVE, "WM_MOVE"},
    {WM_SIZE, "WM_SIZE"},
    {WM_ACTIVATE, "WM_ACTIVATE"},
    {WM_SETFOCUS, "WM_SETFOCUS"},
    {WM_KILLFOCUS, "WM_KILLFOCUS"},
    {WM_PAINT, "WM_PAINT"},
    {WM_CLOSE, "WM_CLOSE"},
    {WM_QUIT, "WM_QUIT"},
    {WM_ERASEBKGND, "WM_ERASEBKGND"},
    {WM_SHOWWINDOW, "WM_SHOWWINDOW"},
    {WM_ACTIVATEAPP, "WM_ACTIVATEAPP"},
    {WM_CANCELMODE, "WM_CANCELMODE"},
    {WM_SETCURSOR, "WM_SETCURSOR"},
    {WM_MOUSEACTIVATE, "WM_MOUSEACTIVATE"},
    {WM_VKEYTOITEM, "WM_VKEYTOITEM"},
    {WM_CHARTOITEM, "WM_CHARTOITEM"},
    {WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING, "WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING"},
    {WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED, "WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED"},
    {SPI_SETDRAGHEIGHT, "SPI_SETDRAGHEIGHT"},
    {WM_HELP, "WM_HELP"},
    {WM_CONTEXTMENU, "WM_CONTEXTMENU"},
    {WM_GETICON, "WM_GETICON"},
    {WM_NCCREATE, "WM_NCCREATE"},
    {WM_NCDESTROY, "WM_NCDESTROY"},
    {WM_NCCALCSIZE, "WM_NCCALCSIZE"},
    {WM_NCHITTEST, "WM_NCHITTEST"},
    {WM_NCPAINT, "WM_NCPAINT"},
    {WM_NCACTIVATE, "WM_NCACTIVATE"},
    {SPI_GETDOCKMOVING, "SPI_GETDOCKMOVING"},
    {WM_KEYDOWN, "WM_KEYDOWN"},
    {WM_KEYUP, "WM_KEYUP"},
    {WM_CHAR, "WM_CHAR"},
    {WM_SYSKEYDOWN, "WM_SYSKEYDOWN"},
    {WM_SYSKEYUP, "WM_SYSKEYUP"},
    {WM_SYSCHAR, "WM_SYSCHAR"},
    {WM_SYSCOMMAND, "WM_SYSCOMMAND"},
    {WM_MOUSEMOVE, "WM_MOUSEMOVE"},
    {WM_LBUTTONDOWN, "WM_LBUTTONDOWN"},
    {WM_LBUTTONUP, "WM_LBUTTONUP"},
    {WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK, "WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK"},
    {WM_RBUTTONDOWN, "WM_RBUTTONDOWN"},
    {WM_RBUTTONUP, "WM_RBUTTONUP"},
    {WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK, "WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK"},
    {WM_MBUTTONDOWN, "WM_MBUTTONDOWN"},
    {WM_MBUTTONUP, "WM_MBUTTONUP"},
    {WM_MBUTTONDBLCLK, "WM_MBUTTONDBLCLK"},
    {WM_MOUSEWHEEL, "WM_MOUSEWHEEL"},
    {WM_XBUTTONDOWN, "WM_XBUTTONDOWN"},
    {WM_XBUTTONUP, "WM_XBUTTONUP"},
    {WM_IME_SETCONTEXT, "WM_IME_SETCONTEXT"},
    {WM_IME_NOTIFY, "WM_IME_NOTIFY"},
    {WM_HOTKEY, "WM_HOTKEY"},
    {0x0313, ": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430377/winapi-undocumented-windows-message-0x0313-stable"},
    {WM_PRINT, "WM_PRINT"},
    {WM_APPCOMMAND, "WM_APPCOMMAND"},
};

std::unordered_set<UINT> unmapped_messages;

std::map<WPARAM, std::string> mk_down = {
    {MK_CONTROL, "MK_CONTROL"},
    {MK_LBUTTON,"MK_LBUTTON"},
    {MK_MBUTTON,"MK_MBUTTON"},
    {MK_RBUTTON,"MK_RBUTTON"},
    {MK_SHIFT,"MK_SHIFT"},
    {MK_XBUTTON1,"MK_XBUTTON1"},
    {MK_XBUTTON2,"MK_XBUTTON2"}
};

constexpr int colw = 40;
std::string message_maker(const char* macro, UINT uMsg, UINT offset) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << macro << " + " << std::hex << (uMsg - offset) << " (" << uMsg << ")";
    return ss.str();
}

inline void DisplayMsg(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    std::string message;

    if (uMsg < WM_USER) {
        // there may be duplicate macros for some messages, so show all of them
        auto[rangefirst, rangelast] = messages.equal_range(uMsg);

        if (rangefirst == rangelast) {
            // unmapped message found, store it
            unmapped_messages.emplace(uMsg);
            rangefirst = messages.emplace(uMsg, ": " + std::to_string(uMsg) + " -- UNMAPPED MESSAGE");
            rangelast = rangefirst;
            ++rangelast;
        }
        message = rangefirst->second;
        while (++rangefirst != rangelast) message += " " + rangefirst->second;
    }
    else {
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/ocm--base
#define REGISTERED_WINDOWS_MESSAGE_BASE (0xC000)
#define SYSRESERVED_BASE                (0x10000)

        if (uMsg < OCM__BASE)
            message = message_maker("WM_USER", uMsg, WM_USER);
        else if (uMsg < WM_APP)
            message = message_maker("(WM_USER) OCM__BASE", uMsg, OCM__BASE);
        else if (uMsg < REGISTERED_WINDOWS_MESSAGE_BASE)
            message = message_maker("WM_APP", uMsg, WM_APP);
        else if (uMsg < SYSRESERVED_BASE)
            message = message_maker("Registered Window Message", uMsg, REGISTERED_WINDOWS_MESSAGE_BASE);
        else
            message = message_maker("Reserved by the system", uMsg, SYSRESERVED_BASE);
    }
    std::cout << std::setw(colw) << std::hex << message << std::setw(18) << wParam
        << std::setw(12) << lParam << "\n";
}

LRESULT CALLBACK ScreenProcess(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    static std::string old_mouse_message;

    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        {
            std::stringstream ss;
            std::string new_mouse_message;
            int xPos, yPos;

            xPos = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
            yPos = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
            ss << std::setw(colw) << "WM_MOUSEMOVE" << std::dec
               << " x=" << std::setw(6) << xPos << " y=" << std::setw(6) << yPos;

            for (auto&[wp, key] : mk_down)
                if (wp&wParam) ss << " " << key;

            new_mouse_message = ss.str();

            if (new_mouse_message != old_mouse_message) {
                std::cout << new_mouse_message << "\n";
                old_mouse_message = std::move(new_mouse_message);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    case WM_NCHITTEST:
        return HTCLIENT;
    case WM_SETCURSOR:
        return TRUE;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        std::cout << std::setw(colw) << "WM_DESTROY" << " ";
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        std::cout << "PostQuitMessage() done\n";
        return 0;
    default:
        DisplayMsg(uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}    

int main() {
    try {
        WindowsClassRegistrator wcr(ScreenProcess);

        // use WS_VISIBLE so that you don't have to call ShowWindow()
        HWND hWnd =
            AssertNEQ<HWND>(NULL, "CreateWindowExW",
                CreateWindowExW(
                    WS_EX_APPWINDOW,
                    wcr.GetAtomAsStr(),
                    L"Title string",
                    WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS, 
                    CW_USEDEFAULT, // x
                    CW_USEDEFAULT, // y
                    0, // width
                    0, // height
                    nullptr,
                    nullptr,
                    wcr.GetInstance(),
                    nullptr
                )
            );

        MONITORINFO mi = { sizeof(mi) }; // mi.cbSize = sizeof(mi);
        AssertNEQ<BOOL>(FALSE, "GetMonitorInfo",
            GetMonitorInfo(MonitorFromWindow(hWnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY), &mi)
        );

        AssertNEQ<BOOL>(FALSE, "SetWindowPos",
            SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOP,
                mi.rcMonitor.left, mi.rcMonitor.top,
                (mi.rcMonitor.right - mi.rcMonitor.left) / 4, // 1/4 of the screen width
                (mi.rcMonitor.bottom - mi.rcMonitor.top), // height
                SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED)
            );

        // paint a rectangle in the window
        AssertNEQ<BOOL>(FALSE, "Rectangle", Rectangle(
            AssertNEQ<HDC>(NULL, "GetDC", GetDC(hWnd)),
            10, 10, 100, 100)
        );

        MSG uMsg;
        while (AssertNEQ<BOOL>(-1, "GetMessage", GetMessage(&uMsg, nullptr, 0, 0))) {
            TranslateMessage(&uMsg); // assertion would depend on message type
            DispatchMessage(&uMsg); // assertion would depend on message type
        }
        DisplayMsg(uMsg.message, uMsg.wParam, uMsg.lParam); // WM_QUIT

        if (unmapped_messages.size()) {
            std::cout << "\nYou have collected unmapped messages: \n";

            for (const auto&[msg, text] : messages) {
                std::cout << "/* 0x" << std::setw(4) << std::setfill('0') << msg << " */ ";
                if (unmapped_messages.count(msg) || text[0] == ':') {
                    std::cout << "{0x" << std::setw(4) << std::setfill('0') << msg;
                }
                else {
                    std::cout << "{" << text;
                }
                std::cout << ", \"" << text << "\"},\n";
            }
        }

        return static_cast<int>(uMsg.wParam);
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << ex.what() << "\n";
    }
    return 1;
} // the registered windows class will be unregistered here, when wcr goes out of
  // scope
```

Comment: this works. I have no idea what's wrong with my code, I will look at them side by side see what the hell I missed

Comment: It's hard to say since I don't have your full code. Btw, using dwStyle `WS_VISIBLE` instead of calling `ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);` separately won't matter. I've now added a class to handle unregistering of the registered class too.

Comment: @AAAbbbCCCddd If you edit your question and make it [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I will edit my answer and try to point out what makes my code work while yours don't so that this question can be removed from the list of unanswered questions on SO.

Comment: It's not working again. I honestly have no idea. No ammount of debugging from me will allow me to figure it out, it works one time and doesn't the other time. Also, even when it was working the registerclass function was still failing. I honestly have no idea what's up. Still looking into it tho so keep an eye on this, maybe I'll figure it out

Comment: Do you mean that if you take the code exactly as I've written it above, it doesn't work? Try again with the updated code. You should at least get a proper error message if this doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, but then please update your question with a [mcve]. It's impossible for anyone to help when you refuse to show your code.

Comment: @AAAbbbCCCddd I've updated it with functions to support in the bug hunt. Use the assertion function templates around your WinAPI calls and you should find if any of them fails. I also added plenty of examples in the code how to use them.

Comment: Damn I really appreciate it. I would also do the same if I was as experienced as you, I love writing code. Happy to say I did not give up on my project yet, still working on it. Will use your code once I get a bit of time and will update my OP with the result and also answer to you

Comment: Sounds great, Happy bug hunting :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified, single source file version of the default Win32 project template that Visual Studio generates for you.  I've just stripped out the stuff related to resources, accelerators, menus, and the About box thing.

```
#include <windows.h>

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
WCHAR szTitle[] = L"Test App";                  // The title bar text
WCHAR szWindowClass[] = L"__TestAppWindowClass__";            // the main window class name

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.

    // Initialize global strings
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance(hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    MSG msg;

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}



//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex = { 0 };

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

//
//   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//        create and display the main program window.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    return TRUE;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE: Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this does not work. there's definitely something wrong with my PC

Comment: @AAAbbbCCCddd That is very doubtful. More likely you are simply not using the API correctly.

Comment: @AAAbbbCCCddd - I did test this program locally myself before posting.  **Can you elaborate on what you mean by "does not work"?**  Does the code even compile for you?  If so, have you debugged through your code or mine (with a debugger) to understand why it might not be working?  Are certain APIs failing?  What does CreateWindow return?  What tool set are you using?  Visual Studio or something else?  Does the process even start?

Comment: Yeah so I fixed the problem. It makes no sense how I solved it. Will answer your question anyway. I can compile it, the program runs but no window appeared. I set the WS_VISIBLE flag, because apparently ShowWindow with SW_SHOW did not do it. I was using VS, yes. Thanks for your help nonetheless